# Test a function for void return in C#

Tags: c#

I want to write a function that takes a function as an argument and then do different things based on whether the passed-in function returns void vs a value.
C# signature checking can't tell the difference so I'm stuck doing it in code.
Is there an easy way to test whether an arbitrary function returns void?

To be clear.  I explicitly am not interested in a compile error.  I just want the equivalent of what I can do for any other object.

```
void IsString(object o) => o is string;

void ElseWhere() {
  object o = 1;
  if (IsString(o)) Bla();
```

However even this gets a compile error claiming the two methods are ambiguous.  It doesn't flag the methods themselves ambiguous but I get an error on the call saying it can't resolve between them.

```
private static bool HasNoReturnValue(Action o) => true;
private static bool HasNoReturnValue(Func<object> o) => false;

...
if (HasNoReturnValue(SomeFunction)) Bla();
```

As do anything I've tried involving typeof:

```
if (SomeFunction is typeof(Func(object>)) Bla();
```

Comment: a `Func` that returns `void` is an `Action`

Comment: What does that mean.  Are you saying I've used an incorrect word in my question?Or perhaps that isn't not possible???

Comment: What's your method signature?

Comment: I've not written it.  I'm still designing.  I want to know if it's possible and how much trouble it is before I take this route

Comment: In that case, what do you mean by "C# signature checking can't tell the difference"? It most definitely can tell the difference between different types of delegates.

Comment: A "function that returns void" and a function that returns something else are *diffferent types*. What you're asking is similar to "Is there a way to tell if an argument is a string or an integer?" I don't know how to answer that question because it is so bizarre. *Of course* you can tell-- the compiler won't let you treat one like the other.

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the down-votes they mean in this case that the question is very light on details and specificity. When it comes to questions that benefit future users, they are best asked with more (than less) detail, clear examples and use cases, and are well received when they are well thought out and formatted, with as much information as needed for the benefit of you, the people who would like to answer and future users

Comment: @JohnWu  I've updated my example with an example showing the compiler CAN'T tell the difference.  It won't compile the line calling HasNoReturnValue saying the call is ambiguous.

Comment: @yaakov I've updated the example to show the compiler can't tell the difference.

Comment: @bielawski What are you passing for `SomeFunction`? I don't see an ambiguous call issue.

Comment: @JSteward Perhaps I should bet you are trying it in LinqPad because I also can't recreate the error there but in Visual Studio 2017 targeting .Net Core 2.1 it will not compile.  I get CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'TestExecutionList.HasNoReturnValue(Action)' and 'TestExecutionList.HasNoReturnValue(Func<object>)'

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @bielawski. I've provided an answer that shows you how it can tell the difference.

Comment: have you considered reflection on the class?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 If there is some particular code you believe should work, please propose it.  From this conversation I don't see how I could pass the function to any procedure and that proc not have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two methods, one of which returns a Boolean and one which returns void.

```
void SomeFunction1()
{
}
bool SomeFunction2()
{
    return false;
}
```

To pass either of these as a pointer to a method, you have to convert them to a delegate. Two types of delegates: `Action` and `Func<bool>`, respectively:

```
var action1 = new Action(SomeFunction1);
var action2 = new Func<bool>(SomeFunction2);
```

You can then write two methods that accept these types as arguments:

```
void AcceptDelegate(Action action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The delegate returns void.");
}

void AcceptDelegate(Func<bool> func)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The delegate returns a Boolean.");
}
```

And call them like this:

```
AcceptDelegate(action1);
AcceptDelegate(action2);
```

Or you could pass the method group directly and the compiler will figure out the type (Why? See [the Microsoft documentation on c# method group conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#method-group-conversions)):

```
AcceptDelegate(SomeFunction1);
AcceptDelegate(SomeFunction2);
```

Either way you call them, you would get this output:

```
The delegate returns void.
The delegate returns a Boolean.
```

The reason this works is the compiler will automatically pick the right one at compile-time, based on the type of the delegate, just as it would pick the overload for any type such as string or integer. This is the type-safe / early-bound way to do it.

If you insist on an "any delegate"/ late binding sort of approach, you could do something like this:

```
void AcceptAnyDelegate(Delegate anyAction)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The function returns a {0}", anyAction.Method.ReturnType);
}
```

Because the signature isn't type specific, you have to pass the specific delegates this time (Why? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474274/2791540)):

```
AcceptAnyDelegate(action1);
AcceptAnyDelegate(action2);
```

And the output would be:

```
The function returns a Void
The function returns a Boolean
```

### Edit

After rereading your comments, I believe the confusion here is due to a misunderstanding of method groups and delegates.

When you write something like this:

```
Foo(Bar);
```

...it appears you believe you are passing to `Foo` a direct reference to the `Bar` method. That is not correct. What you are doing is specifying a method group, which the compiler can then use to infer the type of delegate to pass. If `Bar` is a method with no inputs or outputs, the above code is exactly the same as

```
Foo(new Action( Bar ));
```

...only the creation of the delegate is hidden from you by the compiler.

**All delegates are specifically typed** with respect to their parameters and return type. The `Delegate` base type is abstract and cannot exist in concrete form. So there is no such thing as passing a type-agnostic function reference-- it doesn't exist in c#.

If you really really want to pass something that is type-agnostic, you can ask the caller to pass a lambda expression:

```
Foo( () => SomeFunction1() );
```

You could then parse the expression to figure out the method's inputs and outputs:

```
void Foo(Expression<Action> anyAction)
{
    var mce = anyAction.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    var method = mce.Method;

    Console.WriteLine("The method has a return type of {0}", method.ReturnType.Name);
}
```

Then to invoke the expression you would use:

```
var compiled = anyAction.Compile(); 
compiled();
```

That is the closest you're going to get.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that in order to convert them to delegates I need to know already if they return a value making it essentially the same answer @Alex gave which, in my book equates to - what you want is explicitly impossible.

Comment: Your "anyAction.Method.ReturnType" is intriguing.  Is there any way to call that directly on this function?  Will it return null if there isn't a return value?  I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: "I need to know already" Specifically speaking, you don't need to know anything. The *caller* needs to know. And surely they know what function they are passing (and therefore its delegate type), yes? How could they not? I am not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: Please see my revised answer in which I attempt to address your latest questions.

Comment: Aah, that explains much.  I don't have access to the calling code as I'm trying to inject my code into a foreign app.  But at least I now see why I can't access Method or, in your new example, Body.  They appear to be extensions on Func, Delegate etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's two different types here:

[Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8) for no return type

and

[Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) for a return type

Can you make two different signatures for these two different argument types?

Comment: you were faster....but I would like to share this anyways: https://stackoverflow.com/a/917572/1384539

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick

```
    public static void TakeInAFunc<T>(T aFuncOrAction)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Func<>))
        {
            // some value returned.
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Action<>))
        {
            // it returns void.
        }
    }
```